# React Quill - social media link to embed media on rich text editor

Tags: reactjs, embed, rich-text-editor, social-media, react-quill

I want the react quill rich text editor able to convert link into social media, like this

[link: https://www.tiktok.com/@epicgardening/video/7055411162212633903](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdD2C.png)

My RTE Code

```
import { useCallback, useMemo, useEffect } from 'react';
import ImageResize from 'quill-image-resize-module-react';
import ReactQuill, { Quill } from 'react-quill';
import { message } from 'antd';

import { uploadFiles } from 'utils';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.bubble.css';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';

import './styles.scss';

Quill.register('modules/imageResize', ImageResize);

const RichTextEditor = ({
  editorState,
  onChange,
  readOnly = false,
  setLoading = () => {}
}) => {
  window.Quill = Quill;
  let quillRef = null; // Quill instance
  let reactQuillRef = null; // ReactQuill component

  useEffect(() => {
    attachQuillRefs();
  }, []);

  const attachQuillRefs = useCallback(() => {
    if (typeof reactQuillRef.getEditor !== 'function') return;
    quillRef = reactQuillRef.getEditor();
  }, []);

  const imageHandler = () => {
    const input = document.createElement('input');

    input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
    input.setAttribute('accept', 'image/*');
    input.click();

    input.onchange = async () => {
      const file = input.files[0];
      if (file.size > 1500000)
        return message.error('Image size exceeded 1.5Mb');
      setLoading({ image: true });
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('image', file);
      const fileName = file.name;

      const imgUrl = await uploadFiles(file, quillRef);

      const range = quillRef.getSelection();

      quillRef.insertEmbed(range.index, 'image', imgUrl, 'user');
      let existingDelta = quillRef.getContents();
      const indexOf = existingDelta.ops.findIndex((eachOps) => {
        return eachOps.insert?.image === imgUrl;
      });
      const selectedOps = existingDelta.ops[indexOf];

      if (indexOf !== -1) {
        selectedOps.attributes = {};
        selectedOps.attributes = { alt: fileName };
      }

      quillRef.setContents(existingDelta);
      setLoading({ image: false });
    };
  };

  const modules = useMemo(
    () => ({
      toolbar: {
        container: [
          [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
          ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],
          [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }],
          [{ align: [] }],
          ['link', 'image'],
          ['clean'],
          [{ color: [] }]
        ],
        handlers: {
          image: imageHandler
        }
      },
      imageResize: {
        modules: ['Resize', 'DisplaySize']
      }
    }),
    []
  );

  return (
    <div className="react-quill-wrapper">
      <ReactQuill
        readOnly={readOnly}
        theme={readOnly ? 'bubble' : 'snow'}
        ref={(e) => {
          reactQuillRef = e;
        }}
        value={editorState}
        modules={modules}
        placeholder="Add content of your article!"
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export { RichTextEditor };
```

```
 const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState('');

 <RichTextEditor 
    editorState={editorState} 
    onChange={setEditorState} 
    setLoading={setLoading} 
 />
```

called by parent like this

I've been working on this for almost a week, I really need help

I expected to have an string HTML output, like [this](https://justinmahar.github.io/react-social-media-embed/?path=/story/embeds-facebookembed--main-example) library or image above

My attempts:

Get the social media url typed by user based on link, use that typed link to determined what social media, and use [react-social-media-embed](https://github.com/justinmahar/react-social-media-embed) to give me an output link image above.

I belive(maybe) that the output from react-social-media-embed is jsx, and I need to convert it to html, and parsed it to string.

```
Hello fellow developers,
I found the solution weeks ago. If anybody needs it you can reach me, and I'll answer here.
```